# Call a stored procedure asynchronously with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Entity Framework 6.2.0 and the database-first approach.

When I'm adding a stored procedure to my context, I get a synchronous method for calling it only. I don't see any options to generate an asynchronous method for it.

Is that still impossible in EF?

If so, what is the pattern to call stored procedures asynchronously with EF in an Web API 5.2.4 app preferably not using hand-written string constant for the stored procedure name and using EF-generated code to the maximum extent?

Comment: @MadMyche: Sure, I do :) This question as pointed in its title is specific to the current EF features in this area, if any. If it lacks it, then I'd like to get some good patterns of how people work this around.

Comment: @MadMyche: This tutorial explains how to use SPs for CRUD ops instead of the common approach with entity collections (`DbSet`s) + LINQ queries. It doesn't explain how to call an arbitrary SP asynchronously. Arbitrary SP means it might be unrelated to any entity in your context.